# Flatsome Theme - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

suddenly there is a problem with pagination, or something else in a page i work with Flatsome - Wordpress.
In a certain category page (digital cameras), the pagination seems to work but the products stack in the first page.
For example:
I see the page-1, everything seems ok.
When i hit the page-2, pagination shows page-2 but the products stay at page-1

I tried to deactivated some plug ins, nothing happened, i looked all the aspects (i think) from the theme setting.
Somethin is that i miss

Comment: I somehow found the conflict. I use also the Berocket Filters, i purchased, and these two causes a conflict in the pagination. If someone can help, more so i can have both and would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you purchased something that is causing a conflict, reach out to that developer to help. Since we don't have the error you were getting, there would be no way we could help you.

Comment: I found the solution, i had to change the selectors from ul.products to div.products. because the theme is working different